# What is the input impedance of the ADC the SAMD21 on the Arduino Zero?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, adc, input-impedance

I'm looking through the data sheet and I can't find the answer.

[Datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAM_D21_DA1_Family_DataSheet_DS40001882F.pdf)

Comment: ~3.5k see page 881, table 37-24

Comment: It's actually a bit complicated for an unbuffered ADC like that. It depends on the sample rate. Maybe someone will write a full answer, in the meaning here's a TI [app note](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/spna088/spna088.pdf?ts=1628480932245) to chew on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

41.10.4 Analog-to-Digital Characteristics (ADC) Table 41-23. Operating Conditions.
p.1017

3.5kohm max + Cin=3.5 pF typ ___. Not measured but by design

NOTE :(Rs+Rin)*Cin must settle within sampling interval , so Rin is kept low for higher speed,